# angularjs, ui-router access to parameter at the beginning in the state url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have a frontend web application written enterely in HTML5/JavaScript and the MVC is managed by AngularJS framework using UI-Router.

Now... I have the need to manage more customer with a single application using this pattern:

- all customer have an applicationName (System.String)
- the url to access into the application is [domain]/:applicationName/[view state] like: http://domain.com/MyName/login or http://domain.com/MyName/home/dashboard

so into the config function of Angular's bootstraping file I have to do something like this:

```
 .state('home.dashboard', {
     url: '/:applicationName/home/dashboard',
     templateUrl: '/views/contents/dashboard.html'
  });
```

so the problem is: applicationName is an unique name to retrieve the corrispondent applicationId (System.Guid) stored into the database (this applicationId is used to retrieve the corrispondent applicationName data from the database and so is used into all requests).

so the question: before to resolve the state url can I retrieve the applicationName and do the request to a rest api to get the corrispondent applicationId and store it in an angular service; then go to the state.

is it possible? and if yes, how can I do this?

thanks so much to everyone!

Lorenzo

Comment: have you looked at the ui-router `resolve` state parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use $locationChangeStart event in app run function where you can fetch the application Name from Database (using service/provider).

```
        app.run(["$rootScope", "$location", "$window",function ($rootScope, $location, $window){
             $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
                 alert($location.$$path);

             });

        }])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways. I have a recommendation though,

1. Have a default route and write a controller
2. Inside the controller please ensure to call the API and get the application id
3. Inside the controller you can do the $state.go()
   See: 
   https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls